# What does Conversion law mean as it relates to this method description

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), its fit method is described as such:

> fit(raw_documents) Learn a conversion law from documents to array
>   data

Unfortunately all the definitions I found searching online didn't seem to relate. Unless, its referring to the law of conservation... but I don't see how that fits. So what is this "conversion law" referring to?

Comment: You should probably look at the latest version of the docs... 0.11 is pretty old. [This page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) for the latest stable release is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion law is not a common term in text analytics, which is why this description was changed some time ago (by yours truly). What is really meant is that `fit` causes the transformer to learn how to convert text documents to vectors: it learns a vocabulary from the input documents as well as terms' document frequencies, used in the tf-idf transformation.